# Is there a way to anonymize a list of names by replacing the letters with asterisks in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, anonymize

I have a list of names in a column e.g.:
Bob Adam Smith, Steve Jobs, Stacy Jones

I’d like to use these names for a case study presentation, but they have to be anonymized.

I imagine something like:
B@b A@@m S@@@h, S@@@e J@@s, S@@@y J@@@s

But with asterisks instead of @.

Some people have very long and very short names or some have middle names, so I’m not sure if it’s possible with Excel formulas.

Something like: “=RIGHT(A1,2)&”**** ****”&RIGHT(A3,2)”

Gives me: Bo**** ****th

Which is no good.

Comment: To truly anonymize, the result would have to have nothing in common with the original names, this includes the number of characters etc... Just replace all names with a set number of asterisks *5 or 6 would probably be good. If you need to differentiate between anonymized names, then use numbers (individual 1, or person 1 are good options)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=LET(t,TEXTSPLIT(A1," "),
     e,LEN(t)-(--ISNUMBER(FIND(",",t))),
TEXTJOIN(" ",,
         LEFT(t,1)
         &REPT("@",e-2)
         &RIGHT(t,1+ISNUMBER(FIND(",",t)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create *hash* values for the names - those are really anonymous.

Study my article: [Hashing in VBA using the Microsoft NG Cryptography (CNG) API](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/37112/Hashing-in-VBA-using-the-Microsoft-NG-Cryptography-CNG-API.html?preview=dBrQ1Gub79o%3D)

It's a lot of code, but dead easy to implement:

```
AnonymousName = Hash(FullName)
```

Full code at **GitHub**: [VBA.Cryptography](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Cryptography)